# how to open a hidden file in android programmatically?

Tags: android, text-files, android-sdcard

In my app I created a hidden text file using below code:

```
logfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/.logfile.txt");

if(!logfile.exists()){
    try {
        logfile.createNewFile();

        //Toast.makeText(SimpleIME.this,"File created...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(SimpleIME.this,"IOException : "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This works fine. It creates a hidden file. And then again I want to open that text file when i press a button called `viewlog`.

Code for  `viewlog` goes like this.

```
viewlog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        logfile =    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/.logfile.txt");
         Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + logfile.getAbsolutePath());
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.setData(uri);
         startActivity(intent);

    }

});
```

So when I run this app and when I click this `viewlog` button it force closes the app.

So how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

```
    logfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/.logfile.txt");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + logfile.getAbsolutePath());
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It works..Thanks for saving me..!! what about folders? What if we make a hidden folder and try to open it what should be pass to the setDataandType arguments?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Sorry, I am new to use StackOverflow comment format. I means MIME type is star/star